# Writing a function to set some but not necessarily all parameters in another function

Tags: javascript, arguments, closures

I had a coding interview test that asked the following question which I was not able to fully solve. I'm wondering the best way to do this following my approach -- also sorry this is long.

You are given a function to read in like this (not necessarily 2 parameters):

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The objective is to create a function to initialize some of those variables and again call the function to perform the calculation like, `function setParam(func, params)`. To use this you would do the following:

```
_add = setParam(add, {b:9})
_add(10) // should return 19
```

My solution was to parse the function to see how many parameters there are, then set them using the given parameters but since I barely know javascript I was never able to actually return a function with only some variables set and others still undefined.

(attempt at solution)

```
function  setParam(func, params) {

// varray is an array of the the varriables from the function, func
// ie varray = [a,b] in this test
var varray = /function[^\(]*\(([^\)]*)\)/.exec(func.toString())[1].split(',');

//creates an array, paramset, that has the variables in func defined  
//where possible
// ex paramset = [a,9] if only b was set

var paramsset = []
for (i = 0; i < varray.length; i++) { 
    if (typeof(params[varray[i]]) == "undefined"){
        paramsset[i] = varray[i];
    } else {
        paramsset[i] = params[varray[i]];
    }
}
//////

// need to modify existing function and return with added parameters
// where I'm stuck as this doesn't work.
newfunc = (function(){
    var _func = func;
    return function() {
        return _func.apply(this, paramsset);
    }
})();
newfunc()

}
```

I'm sure I'm not doing this the correct way, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question requires you to do unnatural acts in JavaScript, and therefore is probably a bad interview question.

Comment: I felt like that too, but I'm not familiar with javascript so I assumed there was probably some trick I was missing. (Javascript is not on my resume nor in the job description)

Comment: Anything that makes you figure out the names of formal parameters is in "do not do that" territory

Comment: Doing such kind of code introspection is pointless IMO. You would never perform partial function application this way (that's how this is called). If once whishes to support named parameters then the function should be designed to take a map rather than multiple params e.g. `function doSomething(paramsMap) {}`

Comment: One example of a non-horrible approach to this problem is the old [Functional.js](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) "partial" method. That would let you set placeholders in an argument list into which future arguments would be placed. It didn't require unnatural acts in order to work, and it's pretty useful in some situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certainly not advocating to go towards that solution, but I still implemented something to follow your initial's API design for fun. The `signatures` weak map is necessary in order to preserve the initial function's signature so that we can call `setParams` again on partially applied functions.

```js
var setParams = (function () {
    var signatures = new WeakMap();
    
    return function (fn, paramsToApply) {
        var signature = signatureOf(fn), newFn;
        
        validateParams(paramsToApply, signature.params);
        
        newFn = function () {
            var params = appliedParamsFrom(arguments, paramsToApply, signature.indexes);
            
            return fn.apply(this, params);
        };
        
        signatures.set(newFn, signature);
        
        return newFn;
    };
    
    function signatureOf(fn) {
        return signatures.has(fn)? 
            signatures.get(fn) :
            parseSignatureOf(fn);
    }
    
    function parseSignatureOf(fn) {
        return String(fn)
            .match(/function.*?\((.*?)\)/)[1]
            .replace(/\s+/g, '')
            .split(',')
            .reduce(function (r, param, index) {
                r.indexes[param] = index;
                r.params.push(param);
                return r;
            }, { indexes: {}, params: [] });
    }
    
    function validateParams(paramsToApply, actualParams) {
        Object.keys(paramsToApply).forEach(function (param) {
            if (actualParams.indexOf(param) == -1) throw new Error("parameter '" + param + "' could not be found in the function's signature which is: 'function (" + actualParams + ")'");
        });
    }
    
    function appliedParamsFrom(args, paramsToApply, paramsIndex) {
        var appliedParams = [],
            usedIndexes = [],
            argsIndex = 0, 
            argsLen = args.length,
            argSpotIndex = 0;
      
        
        Object.keys(paramsToApply).forEach(function (param) {
            var index = paramsIndex[param];
          
            appliedParams[index] = paramsToApply[param];
          
            usedIndexes.push(index);
        });
      
        while (argsIndex < argsLen) {
            if (usedIndexes.indexOf(argSpotIndex) == -1) {
                appliedParams[argSpotIndex] = args[argsIndex++];
            }
          
            ++argSpotIndex;
        }
        
        return appliedParams;
    }
})();


function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

var addTo9 = setParams(add, { b: 9 });
var add10To9 = setParams(addTo9, { a: 10 });

document.write(addTo9(10) + ', ' + add10To9());
```

Now, note that JavaScript comes with the [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function which allows to perform in-order partial function application. The first parameter to `bind` has nothing to do with arguments, it's to bind the `this` value.

```js
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

var addTo9 = add.bind(null, 9);

document.write(addTo9(10));
```

And finally, an implementation with a placholder if you need one:

```js
var partial = (function (undefined) {
  var PLACEHOLDER = {};
  
  function partial(fn, partialArgs) {
    return function () {
      return fn.apply(this, applyPartialArgs(arguments, partialArgs));
    };
  }
  
  Object.defineProperty(partial, 'PLACEHOLDER', {
    get: function () { return PLACEHOLDER; }
  });
  
  return partial;
  
  function applyPartialArgs(args, partialArgs) {
    var appliedArgs = partialArgs.map(function (arg) {
          return arg === PLACEHOLDER? undefined : arg;
        }),
        partialArgsLen = partialArgs.length,
        argsLen = args.length,
        argsIndex = 0,
        argSpotIndex = 0;
    
    while (argsIndex < argsLen) {
      if (
        partialArgs[argSpotIndex] === PLACEHOLDER ||
        argSpotIndex >= partialArgsLen
      ) {
        appliedArgs[argSpotIndex] = args[argsIndex++];
      }
      
      ++argSpotIndex;
    }
    
    return appliedArgs;
  }

})();

function add(a, b, c, d) {
  return a + b + c + d;
}

var _ = partial.PLACEHOLDER;

var addTo9 = partial(add, [_, 5, _, 4]);

document.write(addTo9(5, 5));
```

Comment: Holy sh*t! This was a pretty awesome answer, thank you. The bind function makes me so mad lol. I looked everywhere for something simple like that -- I thought it should exist.

Comment: IE8 beware, though there is a polyfill

Comment: @jdphenix WeakMaps cannot be polyfilled unfortunately, but no ones should care about IE8 in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that they might have been testing for knowledge of partial application. (not [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application))

Edit: Edited based upon your comments. This is Crockford's curry function straight from his book.

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

if (!Function.prototype.partial) { 
    Function.prototype.partial = function() { 
        var slice = Array.prototype.slice, 
            args = new Array(arguments.length), 
            that = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { 
            args[i] = arguments[i]; 
        } 
        return function() { 
            return that.apply(null, args.concat(slice.apply(arguments))); 
        }
    }; 
}

var example = add.partial(4);
console.log(example(10)); // output 14
console.log(example(20)); // output 24
```

`var example = adder(4)` assigns `example` to be function with a closure with `a` (in this case 4). When `example` is called like in the `console.log`, it will in effect be returning "the value of a when example was assigned, plus this new number."

Walkthrough of the `partial()` function:

1. Converts arguments to an array
2. returns a function gets passed the arguments given, which can be called later. It has a closure with the previously assigned arguments.

Comment: The issue with this is that it has to be generic. It needed to read in any function with any number of parameters and any number of initialization values. But I do think it needed to be something like this -- seems the right track.

Comment: And still, this function should be called `.partial()`, as it does *no [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application)*!

Comment: Thank you @jdphenix! That, in fact is probably the exact solution they were looking for as it is not nearly as messy as what I had. The only thing to play with would be in setting variables. Since the function need not be a+b but could be a+b**2, etc.